# the Slimbox2 overlay positions over entire site. No prev or next buttons seems like no hover effect

Tags: jquery, plugins, lightbox

I am working with Slimbox2 and I'm getting an overlay that obstructs the large/exposed lightbox image. The overlay goes right over it! This seems to be the functionality out of the box... anyone else experiencing this? Is there a solution?! What am I missing?!! lol *going crazy*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue with the latest jquery 1.9 ...
Please look here: https://code.google.com/p/slimbox/issues/detail?id=36